# bash script needs to read user input and use it as the argument for another command

Tags: linux, string, bash, prompt

So I've been searching the internet for an answer to this, and I can't seem to find anything. I have a bash script that I'm using at the moment, and one of the things that I'd like to do is prompt the user of the script to input a sentence saying what it is that they've used the script for, which then gets passed to CVS. If you don't know what CVS is, it's just a script control function, and the cvs commit that I'm using takes a string and appends it to the files' being committed.

The basics of what I'v tried is as follows:

```
read -p "Please enter what you did here: "
echo
cvs commit -m '$READ' filename.txt
```

The problem is that when I enter a string with multiple words, that `read` interprets that as multiple arguments being passed, and is storing each word as an individual variable, which is breaking my cvs function.

So basically, how do I prompt for a string input and use that input as one variable?

Thanks :)

Comment: `cvs commit -m "$READ" filename.txt` should work.

Comment: `read -p "Please enter what you did here: " -r READ`

Then as anubhava said, put it in double quotes.

Comment: @Ryan Cauldwell: Where do you fill `$READ`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not specified a variable to hold what the user enters, so by default your input ends up in the variable `REPLY`. Per man bash/read:

> If no names are supplied, the line read is assigned to the variable
>   `REPLY`.

Without changing your read statement, you could do:

```
echo
cvs commit -m "$REPLY" filename.txt    # double-quote or kill expansion
```

The proper format for your read is:

```
read -p "Please enter what you did here: " SOMEVAR
```

Whatever the user enters, regardless of whether it has spaces, will end up in `SOMEVAR`. You can then:

```
echo
cvs commit -m "$SOMEVAR" filename.txt    # double-quote or kill expansion
```

Answer (score 1):

You meant

```
read -ep "Please enter what you did here: "
echo
cvs commit -m "$REPLY" filename.txt
```

Comment: From `help read`: _If no NAMEs are supplied, the line read is stored in the REPLY variable._

Answer (score 0):

You can use command argument `-a array` of read function

```
read -a arr -p "Hello "
echo ${arr[*]}
```